# query syntax LINQ could not be translated to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I have used this query to get the user and his list of followers

```
var userAndFollowersQuery =
    from us in _unitOfRepository.User.Where(i => i.Index == currentUserId)
    let fl = _unitOfRepository.TradingAccount
        .Where(i => !i.IsMaster && i.IsActive && i.UserId == us.Index)
        .ToList()
    select new
    {
        User = new
        {
            us.Index,
            us.AccountBalance
        },
        Followers = fl
    };

    var userAndFollowers = await userAndFollowersQuery.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

But EF framework throw me the below exception

```
The LINQ expression 'i => !(i.IsMaster) && i.IsActive && i.UserId == EntityShaperExpression: 
    BackOffice.Service.Data.Models.User
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: Outer
    IsNullable: False
.Index' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I guess this was caused by the **fl** object which was not translated to SQL, it has taken me quite long finding a solution by far. Any help would be appreciated, thank you guys.

Comment: As you're using EF, why do you have "repositories"?

Comment: You can try to remove bits of the LINQ Query to find out which piece of it is not translatable

Comment: There's no EF code in your question. EF neither has nor needs extra "repositories" or "units of work". A DbContext already is a Unit of Work. We can't guess what's going on. In general, LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, it's a query language for EF that gets translated to SQL. You can't use expressions that have no equivalent in SQL, like calling client-side methods

Comment: @Dai  not just repositories but UnitOfRepositories! =)

Comment: The entire query is unusual because of that `let`. What is this trying to do? Is this an attempt to write a correlated subquery that loads accounts related to a Use? The proper and *easy* way to do that is to just use `User.TradingAccounts`. EF will generate the necessary JOINs from the relation between `User` and `TradingAccount`. Precisely because LINQ isn't SQL and DbContext isn't a database connection. DbContext knows the relation between entities and how to convert LINQ into SQL based on them

Comment: @GuruStron yeah I have implemented repository pattern and unit of work pattern in my project

Comment: Try removing `.ToList()` from `let fl = ...` for starters.

Comment: @DucThang that's the point - that's an unnecessary bug. EF already implements this at a much higher level than whatever you tried. This means we now have no idea what your code actually does, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't contain EF. EF neither has nor needs "repositories" and "units of work" as a DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, a DbSet already is a single-entity Repository. They aren't CRUD DAOs. Objects that provide single record access and CRUD operations are Data Access Objects, not repositories.

The error complains that `i => !(i.IsMaster) && i.IsActive && i.UserId == EntityShaperExpression` can't be translated. That's because, assuming  `_unitOfRepository.User` and `_unitOfRepository.TradingAccount` return IQueryable's, there are *two* independent queries. The one on `TradingAccount` is trying to use the one produced from `_unitOfRepository.User.Where(i => i.Index == currentUserId)` without knowing whether the queries are related or not.

This seems to be an attempt to recreate a correlated subquery in LINQ. There's no need for this. LINQ isn't SQL and a DbContext isn't a database connection. LINQ is EF's query language. EF itself will translate a LINQ query to SQL using the schema and *relations* configured in the DbContext. There's no need for JOINs or correlated subqueries if the classes have properties.

Normally, the `User` object should have a `List<TradingAccount> TradingAccounts {get;set;}` property. Assuming the classes follow EF's naming conventions, EF will be able to guess the relations just by the type and property names. Which is why `Index` is a *bad* idea. ID means Identity, not Index.

```
public class User
{
    public long Id{get;set;}
    public decimal AccountBalance {get;set;}

    public List<TradingAccount> TradingAccounts {get;set;}
}

public class TradingAccount
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public bool IsMaster {get;set;}
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}

    public User User {get;set;}
}
```

This allows writing the following queries:

```
var user = _context.Users.Where(u=> u.Id== currentUserId)
                         .Select(u => new {
                             User = new {
                                        u.Id,
                                        u.AccountBalance,                          
                                   },
                             Followers = u.TradingAccounts.Where(a => !a.IsMaster && a.IsActive)
                                                          .ToList()
                         })
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

In query form:

```
var user = (from u in _context.Users
            where u.Id== currentUserId
            select new { User = new { u.Id,
                                      u.AccountBalance,                          
                                    },
                          Followers = u.TradingAccounts.Where(a => !a.IsMaster && a.IsActive).ToList()
                        }
           ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

or, if we want to load the entire user object:

```
var user = _context.Users
                   .Include(u=>u.TradingAccounts.Where(a => !a.IsMaster && a.IsActive))
                   .Where(u=> u.Id== currentUserId)
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This would eagerly load only the `TradingAccount`s that match the filter

Comment: And the reason for the unexplained downvote is ...?